# Error : Wire Method is returning undefined data

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

My requirement is to pass selected accounts on Opportunity Record page to Opportunity Product Record Page.
I have two LWC created for each page.
From Opportunity Record page I get the list of selected accounts and passing it to apex method and storing it in a public list to be used across other methods in the class.

Error: When I try to invoke the wire method to get the selected Account List on Opportunity page I'm getting undefined data.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Please find the code :

Opportunity Page LWC JS:

```
    import callApexMethod from '@salesforce/apex/AccountsOpportunitiesService.createCloneOpportunity'; 

 

export default class opportunityLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
   handleButtonClick(){
        
        callApexMethod({recordId: this.recordId, selectedAccounts: this.selectedSapAccounts})
        .then((result) => {
            
            if(result.responseCode === 'Success'){
                //code
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        }); 
      
       
    }

    //Get Selected Checkbox for SAP Accounts 
    handleRowSelection(event) {
        var selectedRows=event.detail.selectedRows;
        this.selectedSapAccounts = JSON.stringify(selectedRows); 
        
        console.log('selectedSAPAccounts------>' + this.selectedSapAccounts);
        

        if(selectedRows.length === 0){
            this.disabled = true;
        }else{
            this.disabled = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountsOpportunitiesService {
    
    //List to store SAP Account received from Opportunity Page
    public static List<SAP_Account__c> SAPAccountOnOpportunity = new List<SAP_Account__c>();
    
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static AuraMethodResponse callApexMethod (String recordId, 
     List<SAP_Account__c> selectedSapAccounts){ 
        
        SAPAccountOnOpportunity = selectedSapAccounts; 
        System.debug('SAPAccountOnOpportunity----->' + SAPAccountOnOpportunity);  ---> I'm getting the selected Accounts here and storing it in a public List to be used in another method
}

 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)   
    public static List<SAP_Account__c> fetchSAPAccountsFromProducts(){   
        System.debug('fetchSAPAccountsFromProducts SAPAccountOnOpportunity----->' + SAPAccountOnOpportunity);
        return SAPAccountOnOpportunity;
    }

 }
```

Opportunity Product Page LWC: Here I need selected accounts to display in a table

```
import getAllSAPAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/SAPAccountsOpportunitiesService.fetchSAPAccountsFromProducts';

export default class opportunityProductLWC extends LightningElement {

    accountColumns = [
        {
            label: 'SAP Account Name',
            fieldName: 'sapAccount',
            type: 'url',
            typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'sapAccname' }, target: '_blank'}
        },
        { label: 'SAP Account Number', fieldName: 'sapAccountNumber', type: 'string'},
        { label: 'Quantity', type: 'text', fieldName: 'splitQuantityValue'}
    ]; 

   @wire(getAllSAPAccounts)
    SAPAccountList({error, data}) {
        console.log('data received----->' + JSON.stringify(data)); //Here it is undefined ---> How to fetch the selected Accounts Here. 
        if(data) {

            let tempAccList = []; 
            
            data.forEach((record) => {
                let tempAccRec = Object.assign({}, record);  
                tempAccRec.AccountName = '/' + tempAccRec.Id;
                tempAccList.push(tempAccRec);
                
            });

            this.accountsData = tempAccList;
            this.error = undefined;
           

        }
        else if(error){
            this.error = error;
            this.accountsData = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't store information on the Apex class and retrieve it later. LWC controllers are by design static and most calls to this class will occur in different contexts. Your code needs to pass all required information to each Apex method. State can only be stored in the LWC front end.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Thank you for your reply. I tried with LMS also but it didn't work because both LWC are on different record pages.
Could you please suggest any way to store the state in LWC. 
Thank you.